# Firebase InitializeApp with applicationDefault in Github Actions - Error: Invalid contents in the credentials file

Tags: firebase-authentication, github-actions, google-oauth

I have a nodejs app using the following code to initialise the app:

```
import { applicationDefault, initializeApp } from 'firebase-admin/app';
  const app = initializeApp({
    credential: applicationDefault(),
    projectId: FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
  });
```

I'm now trying to run my tests in my github-actions pipeline, first by running the following steps to use workload identity federation to authenticate to google and create the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` env var which contains the generated json file for the service account (with firebase admin permissions). As per [the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#initialize_the_sdk_in_non-google_environments) to set up in a non-google environment.

Relevant Github Actions code:

```
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - id: 'auth'
        name: 'Authenticate to Google Cloud'
        uses: 'google-github-actions/auth@v2'
        with:
          workload_identity_provider: 'PATH-TO-PROVIDER'
          service_account: 'XXXXXXX@XXXXXX.iam.gserviceaccount.com'

       ...install dependencies etc...

       - name: Run tests
        run: |
          pnpm run lint
          pnpm run test
```

**Note**: From the google-github-actions [docs](https://github.com/google-github-actions/auth?tab=readme-ov-file#inputs-miscellaneous), I have ensured that `create_credentials_file` and `export_environment_variables` are set to true, and verified they're present by SSH'ing into the github runner.

However, I'm receiving the following error when the firebase app is attempting to initialise:

> ```
>  Error: Invalid contents in the credentials file
>   at credentialFromFile (node_modules/.pnpm/firebase-admin@11.11.1/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/app/credential-internal.js:496:11)
>   at getApplicationDefault (node_modules/.pnpm/firebase-admin@11.11.1/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/app/credential-internal.js:401:16)
>   at applicationDefault (node_modules/.pnpm/firebase-admin@11.11.1/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/app/credential-factory.js:55:80)
>   at connectFirebase (src/services/firebase.mts:17:17)
>   at Context.<anonymous> (test/test.mts:38:25)
>   at process.processImmediate (node:internal/timers:471:21)
> ```

Any ideas how I can fix this? I would prefer to stay away from adding a long lived JSON key to github actions secrets (added as a value to the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS variable).

Answer (score 0):

When using credentials obtained with Workload Identity, you can get an access token for the Security Token Service,but you cannot use it as an access token to call the Google Cloud API, so you need to get another access token.

- https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/troubleshooting-workload-identity-federation#using-federated-creds
- https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/workload-identity-federation-with-other-clouds#advanced_scenarios

finally I could call firebase api via workflow identity by this code.
https://github.com/lirlia/firebase-remote-config-actions/blob/4fe40103d330447bff63a20e66b8a81c59149c14/src/credential.ts#L34-L82